# Число из переменной

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте WP есть такая функция, которая вставляет код (рекламу) после определенного абзаца в теле статьи.

```
  function pb_ad_into_post($content){
    if(is_single()){
    $pb_post_advert = get_option( 'pb_post_advert' );
        if(empty($pb_post_advert)){
            return $content;
        }
    $pb_post_advert = html_entity_decode( $pb_post_advert, ENT_COMPAT );
        $insertAfter = 3; //номер абзаца, после которого идет реклама
        $closingP = '</p>';
        $contentBlock = explode($closingP, $content);
        foreach($contentBlock as $key => $con){
            if(trim($con)) {
                $contentBlock[$key] .= $closingP;
            }
            if(($key + 1) == $insertAfter){ 
                $contentBlock[$key] .= $pb_post_advert;
            }
        }
        $content = implode('', $contentBlock);
    }
    return $content;    
}
add_filter('the_content', 'pb_ad_into_post');
```

Собственно номер абзаца указывается в строке `$insertAfter = 3;`. Мне нужно, чтобы эта цифра выходила из переменной, берущейся из настройки, например такой

```
$number = get_option( 'number' );
```

Вставляю по разному, не получается. Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Comment: А сам `get_option( 'number' )` что выдаёт?

Comment: Ничего не показывает. Просто пропадает вставка. Ошибок php нет

Comment: И не покажет. - опции `number` ВП не знает https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас не настроена опция скорее всего, так как возвращает "ничего", значит в БД не указана. Для примера я буду иметь в виду название опции `abzac_ads` 
У вас есть три пути:

- Дописать настройку опции к плагину для админ-панели, чтоб в БД не лазить каждый раз, которая будет сохранять данные с установленого поля в `abzac_ads`
- Вручную создать опцию `abzac_ads` в БД, тоесть в таблице `wp_options` добавить строку с `option_name` = `abzac_ads` `option_value` = `нужное нам число`
- Добавить в wp-config.php(лутше не надо) или в тему, что используете `define('CONF_ADS', 'нужное нам число');`

Самый адекватный способ и правильный, тот что первый. Он гибок, а создание страницы в админке(если не хотите редактировать плагин, так как есть шанс потерять изменения при обновлении) занимает минуту, добавление в functions.php например в тему, что используется.

Далее, использывать `get_option('abzac_ads');` в нужном месте, но такой формат слегка не правильный, правильно получать так `get_option('abzac_ads', 3);`, так как в случае, если опцию не находит Вам по умолчанию вернет число 3, которое можно заменить на любое другое, если опцию не нашло или возникли ошибки, в этом случае реклама будет работать всегда.

Если же Вы решили делать третьим и найболее неправильным методом, то для получения пареметра просто пишем в функции вместо числа абзаца `CONF_ADS`, который мы определили ранее. В даном методе минус в том, что вам всегда нужно будет для смены абзаца редактировать файл, что очень плохо и с таким успехом можно редактировать те же число вручную.

P.S.

Вообще, я бы создал метаполе для постов, например "Куда поставить рекламу"(ключ например `kuda_rekamu`), и при фильтре контента, Вашей функции передавал бы параметр дополнительно с `id` поста, для точго, чтоб в функции, которая вызывается при фильтре, можно было использывать конструкцию вместо получения опции, получения метаключа от поста, тоесть `get_post_meta($id,'`kuda_rekamu`,true');`, определить дополнительно значение по-умолчанию 3й абзац, а если ключ указан то использывать значения ключа. В таком случае, для разных постов будет возможность ставить рекламу в разные места, например для `поста 1` поставил рекламу после 10го абзаца, для `поста 2` поставил рекламу после 5го, а для `поста 3` не указал, и ему по умолчанию поставило рекламу после 3го абзаца.